# Using C++, trying to find the largest word in a vector using a for-loop and std::max

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, vector, max

Using C++, I'm trying to put together a for loop that finds the largest word in a vector of strings.  I know its possible to do this by comparing word lengths.  So this is just wondering about some minutiae and learn a few things about C++, I can't figure out why this won't work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::string test = "this is a test string for sentence length ranks";
  std::vector<std::string> words = {"this", "is", "a", "test", "string", 
  "for", "sentence", "length", "ranks"};

  std::string temp = "";
  std::string largest = "";
  for (int i = 0; i != words.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << "words[" << i << "]: " << words[i] << " "; 
    std:: cout << std::endl;
    temp = std::max(temp, words[i]);
    largest = std::max(temp, largest);
    std::cout << "the biggest word is " << largest << std::endl;
  }
return 0;
}
```

It returns this:

[image]

---

**Update:**

The answers here helped point me in the right direction.  As it turns out there is another feature to std::max called 'comp'.  I barely understand it, but this seems to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::string test = "this is a test string for sentence length ranks";
  std::vector<std::string> words = {"this", "is", "a", "test", "string", 
  "for", "sentence", "length", "ranks"};

  std::string tempword;
  std::string longword;
  int longwordint = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i != words.size(); ++i) {
    int wordlength = words[i].length();
    longwordint = std::max(longwordint, wordlength);

    tempword = words[i];
    longword = std::max(longword, tempword, 
              [](std::string longword, std::string tempword) 
              { return (longword.size() < tempword.size()); });

    std::cout << "the biggest word so far is " << longwordint;
    std::cout <<" letters long: " << longword;
    std::cout << " | the tempword is: " << tempword << std::endl;
  }
return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: There is no need to write a loop.  You could have simply used [std::max_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).  Also, where do you actually take the `size()` of each word and use it?

Comment: std::max(string1, string2) on it's own gives me the larger of two strings.  which is why i can't figure out why the loop isn't working.

Comment: The program did exactly as you wrote -- and that is to get the maximum of two strings.  For the strings, the maximum is denoted by which string is placed in order after the other.  Nowhere is `max` going to figure out you really mean the length of the string, *unless you tell it to*.

Comment: your completely right, I was misunderstanding why my little std::max(string1, string2) tests were working.  It was all because this loop uses a vector.  thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

std::max compares things with a normal comparison, which for string, compares their dictionary order, not their length.  So all the results in your loop are as expected.

Comment: Thanks!  This explains why my standalone std:max(string1, string2) tests worked but the vector test didn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::max_element` to find largest word in a vector string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::string test = "this is a test string for sentence length ranks";
  std::vector<std::string> words = {"this", "is", "a", "test", "string", 
  "for", "sentence", "length", "ranks"};

    auto largest = std::max_element(words.begin(), words.end(), [](const auto& s1, const auto& s2){
      return s1.size() < s2.size();
    });
    std::cout << "the biggest word is " << *largest << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is much better than the for-loop.  still though, I'd like to know why the loop isn't working.

Comment: 'std::max(temp, words[i]);` coampare the values not string length.